# Building associate array in post data

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have a form to make changes to a collection of objects. I am able to pass the collection of values, but the keys of that array are 0 - n. Instead I want the keys to be the id of the object that will be changed.

Here is what my form looks like:

```
    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'taps.update', 'data-abide' => true, 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('bar_id', $bar->id)}}
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($beer_tap_object as $beer_tap_id => $current_selection)
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="large-10 columns">
                                {{ Form::select('beertaps[]', [null=>''] + $beers, $current_selection, ['required'] ) }}
                                {{ Form::hidden('taps[]', $beer_tap_id)}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="large-2 columns">
                            </div>
                            <br /><br />
                        </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        {{ Form::submit('Save') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Which results in this post data. I threw in the hidden field to build the array of object ids.

```
  array (size=4)
    '_method' => string 'PUT' (length=3)
    '_token' => string 'asdfasdfasdfasdf' (length=40)
    'bar_id' => string '3' (length=1)
    'beertaps' => 
      array (size=6)
        0 => string '9' (length=1)
        1 => string '11' (length=2)
        2 => string '11' (length=2)
        3 => string '3' (length=1)
        4 => string '2' (length=1)
        5 => string '10' (length=2)
      'taps' => 
        array (size=6)
          0 => string '83' (length=2)
          1 => string '82' (length=2)
          2 => string '81' (length=2)
          3 => string '80' (length=2)
          4 => string '79' (length=2)
          5 => string '78' (length=2)
```

How can I change this so that the values of the second array are the keys of the first array, instead of having the arbitrary increments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type in the name of key

```
<input type="text" name="array[42]" val="something">
```

and you would get $_POST['arr'][42] == 'something'.

When not specifying key and leaving just "[]", every next element will be pushed into this array, which gets you nice ordered array from 0 (0, 1, 2...) (which is what you don't want now).

In Laravel/Blade, try:

```
{{ Form::select('beertaps['.$beer_tap_id.']', [null=>''] + $beers, $current_selection, ['required'] ) }}
```

Comment: The '$beer_tap_id' field will not be interpolated inside single quotes.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect.